# Is there a simpler way for finding a number

Tags: python, list, search, numbers

I'm writing a python script.

I have a list of numbers:

> b = [55.0, 54.0, 54.0, 53.0, 52.0, 51.0, 50.0, 49.0, 48.0, 47.0,
>   45.0, 45.0, 44.0, 43.0, 41.0, 40.0, 39.0, 39.0, 38.0, 37.0, 36.0, 35.0, 34.0, 33.0, 32.0, 31.0, 30.0, 28.0, 27.0, 27.0, 26.0, 25.0, 24.0, 23.0, 22.0, 22.0, 20.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0, 16.0, 15.0, 14.0, 13.0, 11.0, 11.0, 10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]

I need to parse the list and see if the list contains '50'. If it does not,I have to search for one less number 49. if it is not there I have to look for 48. I can do this down to 47. 
In python, is there a one liner code I can do this, or can I use a lambda for this?

Comment: isn't it easier to find the MAX value that is lower or equal to 50 and higher than 46? You can do in in liner way or logarithmic

Comment: `if 50 in b` and `lowestValue = min(b)` and `maximumVal = max(b)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) and [`abs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs):

```
>>> b = [55.0, 54.0, 54.0, 53.0, 52.0, 51.0, 50.0, 49.0, 48.0, 47.0, 45.0, 45.0, 44.0, 43.0, 41.0, 40.0, 39.0, 39.0, 38.0, 37.0, 36.0, 35.0, 34.0, 33.0, 32.0, 31.0, 30.0, 28.0, 27.0, 27.0, 26.0, 25.0, 24.0, 23.0, 22.0, 22.0, 20.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0, 16.0, 15.0, 14.0, 13.0, 11.0, 11.0, 10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
>>> min(b, key=lambda x:abs(x-50))
50.0
>>> min(b, key=lambda x:abs(x-20.1))
20.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
max(i for i in b if i <= 50)
```

It will raise a [ValueError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) if there are no elements that match the condition.

Comment: `b = [51, 52, 53]` :)

Comment: This is good but maybe add a comment that it will raise a ValueError if there are no elements that match the if.

Comment: From [Python3.4+ onwards](http://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-language-changes) you can now pass a default value to `max` and `min` to handle the empty iterable scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
max(filter(lambda i: i<=50, b))
```

or, to handle list with all elements above 50:

```
max(filter(lambda i: i<=50, b) or [None])
```

Comment: @thefourtheye. Thanks for the correction: the second form handles that case

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a generator expression and max.

```
max(n for n in b if n >= 47 and n <= 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
highestValue = max(b)
lowestValue = min(b)
if 50 in b:
    pass
```

Three different ways of finding numbers, highest, lowest and if 50 is in the mix.
And if you need to check if multiple numbers is in your hughe list, say you need to know if `50`, `30` and `40` is in there:

```
set(b).issuperset(set([50, 40, 30]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner without any lambda (raises `ValueError` if value not found):

```
max((x for x in b if 46 < x <= 50))
```

or version that returns None in this case:

```
from itertools import chain
max(chain((x for x in b if 46 < x <= 50), (None,)))
```

Comment: That is actually nicer than using *and*, also you only need a single set of parentheses.

Comment: It would work the same, but are you sure that without parentheses it is generator that is created, or just list?